# React native maps <Circle /> component rendering a black screen when Google is the provider

Tags: google-maps, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-maps

React-Native-Maps  component renders a completely black screen and then app crashes with no error message, all the API components such as Marker, Polygon work fine.

When I remove google as the provide (provider = {'google'}) and the map uses the native IOS Map it works fine and displays my circle. Absolutely confused.

```
<MapView
  provider = {'google'}
  style={styles.map}
  region={{
    latitude: 51.5560,
    longitude: 0.2795,
    latitudeDelta: 0.015,
    longitudeDelta: 0.0121,     
  }}
  showsUserLocation = {true}
  followsUserLocation = {true}
  showsPointsOfInterest = {true}
  maxZoomLevel = {13.3}

>

  {/* // This only works when the map uses the native IOS map and line 35 is removed (provider = {'google'}) */}
          <MapView.Circle 
            key = { 'test' }
            center = { {latitude: this.state.latitude, longitude: this.state.longitude }}
            radius = { 1000   }
            strokeWidth = { 1 }
            strokeColor = { '#1a66ff' }
            fillColor = { 'rgba(230,238,255,0.5)' }
                    />

</MapView>
```

I expect to see my map with the outlined circle. It works when i remove google as the provider and it runs on the native IOS map.

Comment: Solved! Problem was with build configuration

Answer (score 0):

If it's the map style you've created yourself

```js
export const Googlemapstyle = [...]
```

Usage

```js
import { Googlemapstyle } from "path of Googlemapstyle"
    <MapView
    customMapStyle={Googlemapstyle}
    />
```

For `iOS`, in addition to providing the mapStyle you will need to do the following

```js
import MapView, { PROVIDER_GOOGLE } from 'react-native-maps'

// ...

<MapView
  provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
  customMapStyle={Googlemapstyle}
>
```

If you want to get the map style value you want, see [this site](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/).

Comment: Hi, I am not referring to the style of the map. I want to view a circle overlay, it works when I remove Google as the provider and use the native IOS map. The <Circle/> or <MapView.Circle> component is not working for my google map

Comment: Yes, your question raised the question of circle. But your provider is creating a problem. Therefore, set up a provider like my answer and try to solve the problem.

Comment: provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE} is the same as provider={'google'}, that doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: For iOS, you sould be include a customMapStyle as shown my answer.

Comment: I have added a custom map style, the problem is still there. Custom map style lets me style the map, I don't want a custom style, I want to overlay a circle depending on latitude and longtitude.